# Find solution intervals according to the picard theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the initial problem value $x' = x^2, x(0) = x_0 > 0$. What is the maximal value for $T_0$ (as a function of $x_0$) accordind with Picard-Lindelof Theorem and Picard-Lindelof improved theorem, respectively? what maximal value do you get from the explicit solution? (Hint: Compute $T_0$ as a function of $\delta$ and find optimal $\delta$).

this question of the book: ODE and dynamical systems, Gerald Teschl, pg 42.

[here follow both theorems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ar7W.jpg)

I was able to calculate the solution of the initial value problem. But I do not know how to find these ranges according to these theorems.

Comment: For the reader who doesn't own the specific book you're referencing, you should include what $\delta$, $T_0$, and the improved Picard-Lindelof theorem are.

Comment: I put the link with the image of the two theorems

Comment: From the exact solution you should get $T_0=1/x_0$. From Theorem 2.2 you get $T=\frac{\delta}{M}$ with $M=\sup_{|x-x_0|<\delta} x^2 =(x_0+\delta)^2$. Now optimize with respect to $\delta$...